# Why does a subclass of int allow __setattr__ with arbitrary names

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I defined a class `MyInt` as a subclass of `int`, then instantiated an object of it.
I found it legal to set a value to a non-existing attribute `"x"` by assigning `.x = 1`:

```
class MyInt(int):
    pass

a = MyInt()
a.x = 1
```

However if I try to do `.x = 1` to an `int` then it complains

```
b = 0
b.x = 1


AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/pd/rtb4xpwj0cdd6gk9jr3z3_280000gn/T/ipykernel_66385/2856995082.py in <module>
      1 b = 0
----> 2 b.x = 1

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'
```

My question is: if `MyInt` inherits all the methods from `int` without overriding, why does `setattr` behave differently on their instances?

edit: by `setattr` here I meant `__setattr__`.

Comment: I assume you mean `__setattr__`? That method hasn't changed, what's changed is that it now had a `__dict__`, as *all user defined types will be default*, which allows `__setattr__` to handle arbitrary names

Comment: You can suppress the default `__dict__` by defining `__slots__ = ()` inside the class.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Interesting, thanks! Indeed, ```a = MyInt();
b = 0;
set(dir(a)) - set(dir(b))``` then i got ```{'__dict__', '__module__'}```